# Unsure how I resolved a Docker networking issue to pkg repos

Tags: ubuntu, docker, systemd

Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2 on Ubuntu 15.10

A month and a half ago I suddenly noticed that when I built a docker image I was consistently getting errors like the following with `apt` in Ubuntu containers and `dnf` in Fedora containers:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com wily Release.gpg
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com wily-updates Release.gpg
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com wily-security Release.gpg
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora' from 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-22&arch=x86_64': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-22&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]
```

For troubleshooting I tried spinning up a Vagrant instance of Ubuntu 14.04 and it grabbed packages from the repos with `apt` just fine.

By simple scientific experimentation this meant I had a networking issue from within Docker itself. I tried:

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

to of no avail. Then I tried:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

which DID fix the issue and then the images I build can grab packages from Fedora and Ubuntu repos just fine. I find it unsatisfactory that I fixed a problem with agnostic heuristics. Could someone please explain to me why what I did fixed the problem and why this problem suddenly started occurring in the first place, so I can set some kind of automated trigger for it for the future and avoid this occurring again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good first step to understanding what was going on would be to check your logs. Some usefuul commands to check the logs might be:

```
# View logs specific to docker
journalctl -u docker

# View logs for a specific docker container
docker logs name-of-your-container
```

If you want further help understanding what happened, post some related logs for review. However, StackOverflow is not the best place for systemd questions. Consider http://askubuntu.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is unclear to me what the source of the issue was here (docker, systemd, networking, etc.), or what route to go for debugging, so I did not know which of the several relevant Stack Exchange sites to post this on and just went with the norm.

Comment: SO is for questions directly related to programming.